# Bounded sets and uncountablity

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If $S$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $\sup S \not \in S$ and $\inf S \not \in S$  , then can we say that $S$ is uncountable ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The set $(0,1)\cap \mathbb Q$ is bounded, countable and does not contain its supremum and infimum.

Answer (score 4):

Hagen's example is probably the easiest to write down, but you can also construct a minimal example quite easily: the set

$$\left\{-1+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup\left\{1-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$

also works.